# Is there a bug/issue tracking system which integrates with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, integration, bug-tracking

I've used Trac/Subversion before and really like the integration. My current project is using Mercurial for distributed development and it'd be nice to be able to track issues/bugs and have this be integrated with Mercurial. I realized this could be tricky with the nature of DVCS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[TracMercurial](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial) integrates Trac with Mercurial. [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) provides free Mercurial hosting with Trac integration.

The idea is that you have a central repository as your master and upload all the subsidiary changes from local repositories into the main one.

Comment: Use this link: http://www.assembla.com/free_mercurial_hosting to create free open source Mercurial repo with Trac integration. I google a lot before found this link...

Answer (score 18):

I'd also like to add [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) to the list.  I started with Trac, but I found the mercurial support (and the administrative interface for everything) to be much better in Redmine.

Comment: And Redmine is way better if you are running multiple projects.

Answer (score 12):

FogBugz has tight [integration with Mercurial](http://kilnhg.com) through their [Kiln](http://kilnhg.com) product.

Comment: Kiln (http://kilnhg.com/) provides even tighter integration between FogBugz and Mercurial

Comment: and it has free student version!

Answer (score 4):

[BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) now supports Mercurial integration in the same way it supports Subversion and git.  BugTracker.NET is a free, open source, ASP.NET [bug tracking](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) system.

Other free, open source bug trackers that support Mercurial:

- Trac -
  http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial
- Redmine -
  http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineRepositories
- Roundup -
  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook.   The Mercurial development team themselves use Roundup.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a plugin to integrate Mercurial with [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/). See the [webpage](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/Mercurial+Plugin) for the plugin.

Comment: Plugin Not Updated To Work With Current Jira Release 4.3
Integration only via FishEye

Answer (score 3):

Mantis has a beta integration for Mercurial: [blog-post](http://www.mantisbt.org/blog/?p=83)
and [code](http://git.mantisforge.org/w/source-integration/dhx.git?a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/hgweb).

Answer (score 2):

[Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/) is a distributed bugtracking system that supports Mercurial.

Comment: This looks promising, but very experimental.  Do you know of any kind of tutorial for installing, setting up, and using?  The website seems pretty limited and/or broken at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Jira integrates using a plugin.  Its a great tool.

http://www.atlassian.com

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a [command-line bug tracker called b](http://www.digitalgemstones.com/projects/b/) for Mercurial which, although it's not as powerful as Trac and the like, is exactly what a lot of situations call for.  It's best feature is how easy it is to set up - install the Mercurial extension, and all your repos have a bug tracker at their disposal.  I find this incredibly useful on smaller projects that I can't/don't want to set up with a fully fledged tracker living on a server somewhere, just `hg b` and go.

Comment: That is very interesting , i am thinking about developing a web frontend for it for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to another suggestion, you can try [Artemis](http://www.mrzv.org/software/artemis/).

Though I haven't used it yet, it looks easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [BugzillaExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension) for adding a comment to a Bugzilla bug each time you mention its number.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a Trac plugin that integrates some Mercurial functionality that TracMercurial Plugin doesn't support yet, it's called TracMercurialChangesetPlugin. It allows you to search in your changesets, to have the cache synced, to view a changelog in your related tickets...

You can read about it at http://tumblr.com/x8tg5xbsh